# wavelet frequency using pywt package

Tags: fourier

Let's say a signal is measured every 5 minutes:

1. What is the highest frequency wavelet component of this signal (using Morlet wavelet with pywt python package)?
2. What frequency does scale 1024 correspond to (referring to "scales" parameter in the pywt python package)?
3. Would it be possible to measure wavelet components which have a period of less than or equal to 1 minute?